# While loop with skip on first iteration?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, while-loop

I am trying to write this while loop that automatically presses the next button on the first page, but then after abides by the conditions I have set in the while: else: part. How do I automate the first click without conditions because right now it automatically getting closed by following the else: condition.

For more context my_url is the first page of the sneaker website.
There are 34 shoe pages to progress through, but rather than doing it by page numbers I am just trying to advance through the pages so its adaptable to other uses. When it reaches the last page and you click the next button it returns back to page 1. Which is why I have set up the else statement to quit when back to my_url.

```
#Once done scraping page, clicks next page button until it returns to page 1
    def next_page(self, driver):
        next_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/ul/li[3]/button')
        next_button.click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        while driver.current_url != my_url:
            next_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/ul/li[3]/button')
            driver.implicitly_wait(15)
            #run sneakers program again
            #scraper.main_page(driver)
            #scraper.x_path_creator(driver)
            #scraper.shoe_page_scrape(driver)
            scraper.next_page(driver)


            else:
                print("Scraping for this shoe is done.")
                driver.quit()
```

Comment: Try removing the else condition. you can simply put the 'quit' outside the while loop since the while loop will end when the url is the back to the first page again. You can add an init flag to not break the while loop when you are in it with the url for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Well one option would be to convert this to a "do...while" loop instead, so that the first iteration is always executed and the end condition is checked at the end of the loop instead of the start.

Python does not have a "built-in" do...while loop, the normal way to do this is:

```py
while True:
   <insert code here>
   if <condition>:
      break
```

or some variant thereof. Note that since the condition here is an *exit* condition, it's the reverse of the one for a `while`, so you'd have

```py
        while True:
            next_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/ul/li[3]/button')
            driver.implicitly_wait(15)
            scraper.next_page(driver)

            # stop if back at first page
            if driver.current_url == my_url:
                break
```

Also your `else` clause doesn't seem useful: Python's `<loop>: else:` construct is a bit odd, but its point is to differentiate between "normal termination" and *explicit* termination (through a `break`): the `else` clause is only executed in case of normal termination.

Not only are you not using `break` in your code, even if you were you'd probably want to terminate the driver (or not, as the driver doesn't really belong to that function it seems risky).